# Direct output from Python Fabric function to file on remote host

Tags: python, output, stdout, fabric

I need to know how to direct the output from a function in Fabric to a file on a remote host.

I have a host that I run my fab commands from, let's call it mainhost. I have a host, testhost, and I run a "date" command via fab on this host to get testhost's date. I want to print this date command output into a date.txt on testhost.

So the fabfile sits on mainhost, connects to testhost and asks for its date, and I want testhost's date to print to a file which is one testhost. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

You can simply run the below command:

```
run("date > date.txt")
```

This will run the command date and redirect it to date.txt.